# Make wget create an empty file for everything it downloads?

Tags: wget

I am using wget to copy a directory structure from a web server I don't control. I don't care about the content of each resource on this webpage, I just want to create directories and files to mirror the structure of the webserver. Basically create a lot of directories that contain a lot of files, files that are as empty as possible (a few bytes per file is no problem).

Can this be done using wget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a workaround. Downloaded with wget using mirror in one terminal and then in a second terminal I run this oneliner

```
while true ; do date; time find /tmp/test/ -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} \; ; sleep 36000; done
```

This empties every existing file and then pauses for ten hours and run again. "Good enough" for my purposes.

Answer (score -1):

According to `wget`'s man page --mirror is what you are looking for:

```
--mirror
       Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on
       recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and
       keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N
       -l inf --no-remove-listing.
```

Comment: Not really. I am performing an -m operation right now and it has used up 200 GB of space so far. Hence my question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realized you wanted empty files. I don't know of any specific paramenter, but you can use `--spider` to create the directory structure. It will also download an remove files, so if you redirect that output to a file you can launch a simple command that reads that file and recreates with `touch` the missing files.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
wget --spider -r --no-parent http://your.url.com/
```

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: Well, depends on the protocol. If http, the protocol doesnt really do directory structures, so one would get a listing of the links being crawled in the output. I was thinking that maybe the user is pointing it to a ftp site instead, which does do directory structures. Then one could trawl the output and write a script to recreate the output?

Comment: This is http so it has to parse the content of what is downloaded.

Answer (score -2):

i had same issue, use `wget -O - 'URL'` it will delete empty file automatically and your issue will get resolved

```
wget -O - 'http://www.google.com'
```

- `-O` to download output file
- `-` to delete that file

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  This doesn't appear to answer the question.  `wget -O -` simply sends the downloaded file to stdout -- it doesn't create empty files, nor does it recurse and create the directory structure.